# fblike api of facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

hi i am using fblike api of facebook. this is working fine. i am using this script

when i open this page a text "fblike"and facebook icon are showing.but when i click on this a popup window opens and asking for login on facebook.
my question is that when user like this page the text which is display previously "fblike" change to "1 person".
can i stop this. i just want when user like this the texe should not be change.
I can do this or not?

Comment: I think the number of likes is part of the plugin. It comes in as an iframe and I don't think you have any control of it.

Comment: nop you cannot hide that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: You cant do that... :)

But you can achieve this by adjusting height and width of [STANDARD LIKE BUTTON](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) which will hide other part of that plugin (users, counter, etc) :)